# Is there a way to force the Visual Studio document tabs to a specific width?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

Document tabs in Visual Studio are sized to the name of the file as it appears on the tab.  This means that the size of each tab that is open is contingent on the size of the text of the file name.

Is there a setting buried somewhere that will allow me to keep all tabs the exact same width?

**Why does this matter?**

For those that must know a reason for this request, I often work in sizable projects which someone else originally created.  While researching functionality of code, I'll often open up over 10 documents, tracing paths or researching behavior.  When I'm finished with my research, I'll often have to close the previous 3-7 tabs to get back to my original document and unclutter my work area.

I know this seems like a minor nuisance but since every file name is different, you can't keep your mouse in one location and click the the left-button 3-7 times in rapid succession to close all pertinent documents.  You have to float the mouse back and forth, for every tab, because of the variance in tab size.

I'd prefer to just set it so that all tabs are the same size, regardless of the length of the file name.  Can this be done with reasonable effort?

I am using Visual Studio 2015, so I would like an answer for that version of VS.  However, once I upgrade to VS 2017, I'd like to make the same change to that environment.

If the answer for either version is different, I would prefer an answer for both instances of VS.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try Productivity Power Tools.

The feature "Vertical tabs" is what you need.

> Document tabs are shown vertically, allowing you to fit more tabs than are normally visible when shown horizontally.

For VS 2015 https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioProductTeam.ProductivityPowerTools2015

For VS 2017 https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioProductTeam.ProductivityPowerPack2017

**Updated:**

Productivity Power Tools also support customizing min/max tab width. You can find it from Tools>Options...>Productivity Power Tools>Custom Document Well>Advanced
[image]

Comment: Possibly, but I do put often split my screen, so I can look at code side-by-side.  Having vertical tabs will actually shrink my workspace, especially working from my laptop.  This does provide a solution, though a less than perfect one.  Still, I'll give this a try and see if there are other options.

Comment: Actually, this tool does provide a solution, but there is something better than what you suggest. From the Tools>Options...>Productivity Power Tools>Custom Document Well>Advanced option, there is a place to set the max/min tab width.  Forcing all tabs to the same width solves the problem.  Update your answer as such, and I'll give you the answer mark.  Thank you.

Comment: I just checked it and saw the place to set tab width. :D

Comment: I installed Productivity Power Tools 2015 and set the document tabs to vertical. It has no scroll bars for the pinned tabs. New column is added for the excess pinned tabs instead of providing a scroll bar. So it result to taking more space area and making the window for viewing the content of opened document smaller.

Comment: Any news for visual studio 2019? I can't find the tab option.

Comment: @Enrico Options->Environment->Tabs and Windows

Answer (score 11):

In VS2022 this is built in under Tools-> Environment -> Tabs and Windows

[image]

Comment: This is excellent to hear.  About time something like this showed up in VS. My team is still stuck on VS 2019, and I can confirm it's not in there.  Thanks for posting this!